# HTML widget API not displaying unless refreshed in REACT app

Tags: html, reactjs, widget

I am calling a weather widget API. A JS script tag is provided and  tag. It is working only if the page is refreshed. If my react app redirects to the widget using react-router, the widget will not be displayed. How can I resolve this problem?

```
        <Fragment>
        <Grid container   
            alignItems="center"
            justify="center" 
            spacing={0}   
            > 
            <Grid item xs={12} >
            <a class="weatherwidget-io" href="https://forecast7.com/en/n37d86144d77/laverton/"
             data-label_1="LAVERTON" data-label_2="WEATHER" data-theme="original" 
             data-basecolor="#d9d9d9" data-textcolor="#000" data-accent="rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)" data-highcolor="rgb(255, 99, 132)" data-lowcolor="rgb(255, 159, 64)"
             data-mooncolor="rgb(255, 159, 64)" data-cloudcolor="rgb(54, 162, 235)" data-raincolor="#000" data-snowcolor="#64b5f6" data-suncolor="rgb(255, 159, 64)" >LAVERTON WEATHER</a> 
            </Grid>
        </Grid>  
</Fragment>
```

Comment: How are you doing the redirection to this widget with `react-router` ?

Comment: import { Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

<Switch>
<Route path="/" exact component={LoginUI} />
    <ProtectedRoute path="/Home" exact component={Home} />
  </Switch>;

The widget is in the Home Component

Comment: And how is the widget used in your `Home` component ?

Comment: function Home(props) {

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}  >
    <Grid container spacing={8} /*style={{backgroundColor: "#D9D9D9"}}*/>
          <Grid item xs={12} md={3} >  
              <Widget/>

<Widget/> contains another function component
function Widget(props){
    return (
         //THE code above
)

Comment: I imagine it is because the function they provide that finds the tag and places an image has already run when you route to this page. As such you probably need to make that provided function run when your component mounts

Comment: Hello! Yes, I think you just confirmed my suspicion too. Seems like i have to rewrite the JS in a useEffect.